# Date difference in mysql based on 360 days

Tags: mysql

I working on a financial project where i need to calculate the difference of arrear days. If I use the method datediff() of mysql then it returns the result based on 365 days. I need the result based on 360 days. if use the following sql query

```
select datediff('20140908','20130908') from dual;
```

mysql returns the date difference 365. This is the actual date difference but in accounting/Financial calculation the difference is exactly one year (360 days). This is what I want. The result should be 360 instead 365.
Currently I want to use US standard.

Comment: 'I need the result based on 360 days.' Please elaborate

Comment: You first need to define which 360-day _standart_ (e.g. US or European) you would like to use, then you should show use what you already tries, and explain where your problems are.

Comment: I also encountered this question. Here is a solution: http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21912790/DATEDIFF360.html

Answer (score 1):

to get the same result like Excel, I found the following code to use in MySQL:

```
    select case 
when (day(Startdate)>=30 or Startdate=last_day(Startdate) then
    case
    when(day(Enddate)>=30) then
        30*(12*(year(Enddate)-year(Startdate))+month(Enddate)-month(Startdate))
    else
        30*(12*(year(Enddate)-year(Startdate))+month(Enddate)-month(Startdate))+days(Enddate)-30
    end
else
    30*(12*(year(Enddate)-year(Startdate))+month(Enddate)-month(Startdate))+days(Enddate)-days(Startdate)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
TO_DAYS(date2) - To_DAYS(date1)
```

It returns the number of days between date1 and date2. Then you can do with the result what you need.

Comment: Hi Petr, This query also returns 365 days.

Answer (score 0):

sdate = from date
edate = to date

this calculate the days between the 2 date, taking into account that a month is 30 days, 1 year is 360 days, and checking if the date are at the end of the month, so e.g. from 1.1.2019 to 28.2.2019 = 60 days etc.

to be 1 month or 1 year, the edate should be a day before, so 1.1 - 31.1 = 30 days, 1.1 - 1.2 = 31 days

> SELECT GREATEST(
>                   0,
>                   (YEAR(DATE_ADD(edate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) - YEAR(sdate)) * 360 +
>                   (MONTH(DATE_ADD(edate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) - MONTH(sdate)) * 30 +
>                   (
>                       IF(DAYOFMONTH(DATE_ADD(edate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(edate, INTERVAL 1 DAY))), 30, DAYOFMONTH(DATE_ADD(edate, INTERVAL 1 DAY))) -
>                       IF(DAYOFMONTH(sdate) = DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(sdate)), 30, DAYOFMONTH(sdate))
>                   )

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late here, but posting my solution for future reference

```
CREATE FUNCTION `DAYS360_UDF`(sdate DATE, edate DATE)
RETURNS INTEGER
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE sdate_360 INTEGER;
    DECLARE edate_360 INTEGER;
    SET sdate_360 = ( YEAR(sdate) * 360 ) + ( (MONTH(sdate)-1)*30 ) + DAY(sdate);
    SET edate_360 = ( YEAR(edate) * 360 ) + ( (MONTH(edate)-1)*30 ) + DAY(edate);
    RETURN edate_360 - sdate_360;
END
```

Usage -
`select DAYS360_UDF('20130908', '20140908')`